# Flex. Stop the movie

Tags: apache-flex, preloader

I loaded an swf movie into my flex application using an `Image` tag.

```
<mx:Image id="preloader" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"  scaleContent="false"
         source="@Embed(source='/assets/swf/preloader_small.swf')"  
         horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="center"/>
```

It is an animated preloader. Can someone tell me how to stop the preloader animation (like calling stop() method in a `MovieClip`).  Without uploading the animation and etc

best
Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

```
stop()
```

Anytime the playhead encounters a stop action on a frame, it will stop on that frame. You will then need actions to tell the playhead to move along to the next scene or frame. You can loop a scene by adding a goto action on the last frame that sends it back to the first frame.....